# How did Bobby Bacala climb up so high in the Family ranks without popping his cherry?

Tags: the-sopranos

In the episode [*Soprano Home Movies*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soprano_Home_Movies) (S06E13), we learn that Bobby Baccaliery has never "popped his cherry", that means

> he never killed a man.

However, Bobby has been promoted capo in the episode [*For All Debts Public and Private*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_All_Debts_Public_and_Private) (S04E01).

From what I learnt in these crime organisations, it is the kind of mission that they all have to do once in a while, to keep them commited and have their hands dirty.

So how did he gain trust from the other members of the family, and climb the ranks of DiMeo organisation, without ever commited this act?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Wiki page on Made Men](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Made_man):

> Performing a contract killing to become a made man is also known as
>   getting or earning one's "button" or becoming a so-called "button man"
>   or hitman for the Mafia. However, earning one's "button" does not
>   always involve killing; **"heavy earners," or experienced associates who
>   have not necessarily murdered for the Mafia but instead make
>   significant profit for the Mafia through illegal activities, have in
>   the past earned their "button," or become made men**, due to their other
>   valuable contributions beyond contract killing. Though valued by
>   higher ranking members for their economic contributions, "heavy
>   earner" made men that have not committed a murder for the Mafia but
>   are instead initiated for their illegal economic contributions are
>   sometimes looked down on or derided by those made men that have
>   committed murder in order to be initiated; made men that have carried
>   out killings may mock or accuse those made men initiated due to their
>   economic contributions as having "bought their button" (as opposed to
>   "earning one's button" or "making one's button" through murder).

Bobby was the son of a well-respected gangster, so there really was no need to have him commit a contract killing to prove his loyalty.  And he was a very good earner, which is what allowed him to ascend through the ranks.